# Process data after using Datatables server side on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I have a table in database with 73k records.
So I want to show it in only one table on view using Datatables.

---

This is table should be:
[Datatables in client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohfjW.png)

I already have a table with datatables but It's limited item.
The first column is not in database, 
"Show Image" column is special feature, when manager hover over this text, the image shown
I want to use datatable in server side to load all data with changing the appearance.
So I make a controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
use App\Models\GS1;
class DataTablesController extends Controller
{
    private $sa24Repository;

//    function __construct(SA24Repository $sa24Repository)
//    {
//        $this->sa24Repository = $sa24Repository;
//    }
    public function getIndex() {;
        return Datatables::of(Product::query())->make(true);
    }
}
?>
```

with a simple view:
[Products table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BONkk.png) 
It work well but when I type in search input, It search all column.
And I have to add this code to using filter:

```
<script>
    $('.testTable').dataTable();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
    $('.testTable').dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '/datatables',
        columns: [
            {data: 'gtin'},
            {data: 'brand_name'},
            {data: 'description_short'}
        ]
    });
</script>
```

If I remove this codes:

```
columns: [
    {data: 'gtin'},
    {data: 'brand_name'},
    {data: 'description_short'}
]
```

When I search Browser logged:

```
Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
    at Ae (all.js?v=1484881746:6)
    at k (all.js?v=1484881746:5)
    at j (all.js?v=1484881746:5)
    at M (all.js?v=1484881746:5)
    at U (all.js?v=1484881746:6)
    at all.js?v=1484881746:5
    at d (all.js?v=1484881746:5)
    at Object.success (all.js?v=1484881746:5)
    at d (all.js?v=1484881746:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (all.js?v=1484881746:2)
```

and I can't search anything

So could you help me to using datatable to search any columns I want to,
and I don't have to add this snippet in script:

```
columns: [
    {data: 'gtin'},
    {data: 'brand_name'},
    {data: 'description_short'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the columns array determines what to display in the Datatables. Think about it, if the client doesn't even know what columns to display, how would it render the table?

If you want to only search limited columns, you can add `searchable: false` in columns like so (say you dont want to search based on brand name):

```
columns: [
    {data: 'gtin'},
    {data: 'brand_name', searchable: false},
    {data: 'description_short'}
]
```

Comment: Thank you! Please tell me how to format the data after ajax.

Comment: To format the data table, you can use styling options: https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes

Answer (score 0):

I have already fixed this by modifying in DatatableController. And it worked well